# PHP fetch array mysql

Tags: php, mysql, echo, element

I have this piece of code:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users (name, email, joined) VALUES (?, ?, ?)') or die ('Error.');
$query->bindValue(1, $_POST['username']);
$query->bindValue(2, $_POST['email']);
$query->bindValue(3, time());

$query->execute();

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users;');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    echo ('<div style="font-weight: bold;">' .$row['name']. '</div>');
    echo ($row['email']);
    echo ('<br>');
    echo ('Posted: ');
    echo date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($row['joined']));

}

}
```

which it accuses this error:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\WebServer\htdocs\newsSite\register.php on line 21

and on another file (below), it works fine, but i don't see the difference between them:

```
<body>
<?php

$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM posts;');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    echo ('<div style="font-weight: bold;">' .$row['title']. '</div>');
    echo ($row['post']);
    echo ('<br>');
    echo ('Posted: ');
    echo date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($row['date']));

}

?>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql_*` and PDO ?

Comment: Do you have a `PDO` connection *and* a `mysql_connect` connection?

Comment: Why are you using PDO and mysql_*?

Comment: You can remove your 3rd bind by using `NOW()` which is a MySQL function and will automatically fill the field with the current time. Example: `INSERT INTO users (name, email, joined) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())`

Comment: I thought that was the only way to bind the values that way (?, ?, ?), the insertion on db works fine thou

Comment: Change your code from $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users;'); to $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users;')  or die(mysql_error()); for error tracing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, this my code snippet I have used long before,

```
    // PDO
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1', 'example', 'example');

print '<h3>PDO: simple select</h3>';
foreach($pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM users;' ) as $row)
{
    //Fetching data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is (probably) that your query returns false (hence "boolean"), due to some error in the query string or logic.  Try "SELECT 1" instead of your query string and if it works well, you'll know for sure that the difference (the cause) must be in the query.

Answer (score 0):

put one function after this line ,

```
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users;');
echo mysql_error();
```

you have a error into query .